# PHP generate multiple form fields

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I am working on a system to edit/create an online food menu.

On the system that creates/edits the menu I would like the user to be able to enter a new item and price in two form fields and then press 'add another item' in turn this generates another form field. The user can keep pressing 'add another item' or simply submit the form.

Ideally it would keep generating forms fields then when the form is submitted an I handle the POST array and do the DB work.

I'm just not too sure on how I can allow the user to essentially keep adding form fields.

This is system is currently written in PHP.

Hi, Looking into this and my current code, this issue I see is that the form itself is also dynamically generated from database results. Your idea I can see working when I create an entirely new menu, but what if I want to edit a current menu and add a new item to it.

This is the code that generate the current form.

```
if($menuItems->count()) {

    echo '<form class="updateMenu" action="" method="post">';
    echo '<table  class="gridtable gridtableMenu">';
    echo '<tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Item Price</th></tr>';

    foreach($menuItems->results() as $item){                                               
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="menu-name"><input type="text" name="itemName[]" value="' . $item->item_name . '" required></td>';
        echo '<td class="menu-price"><input type="number" step="any" name="itemPrice[]" value="' . $item->item_price . '" required></td>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' . $item->id . '">';
        echo '</tr>';                                        
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="updateMneu" value="Update Menu">';
    echo '</form>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="error">No items have been added to this menu</div>';
}
```

Comment: You could use jQuery / Ajax for this. Simply detect when the "add item" button is pressed and then append another set of fields.

Comment: Hi, Ill look into this now, will this allow me to add two form fields at a time i.e. there are 2 input fields to each row?

Comment: You can make it add as many fields as you want.

Comment: Hi, again thanks for the help. I have stumbled across a problem, could you see the edited question?

Comment: The idea is still the same, the difference would be where to append the new addtional fields, You would just have to add the existing fields identification details to the new, if for example the input fields name needs to be `name=Me[123]` then that can also be achieved with jQuery :)